# How to get javascript to render in views injected into my layout in Asp.Net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

I am creating a simple website with a single layout in Asp.Net MVC 4. The layout has Javascript tags in the head like so:

```
<script src=@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery.min.js")></script>
<script src=@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery.dropotron.min.js")></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery.slidertron.min.js")></script>
<script src=@Url.Content("/Scripts/skel.min.js")></script>
<script src=@Url.Content("/Scripts/skel-layers.min.js")></script>
<script src=@Url.Content("/Scripts/init.js")></script>
```

This renders fine when I first load the website/page.

The project uses the typical URL/Home/Index route as the default - but when I call this explicitly by adding '/Home/Index' to the URL the page is rendered without any styling. Any page other than the home as it loads is rendered without style even though they are all just views being injected into this same layout with this same Javascript in the head.

Any ideas why the Javascript isn't being rendered in all of my views?

Comment: Make sure you have the right layout reference on top of your view .
@{
    Layout = "~/link to your shared layout";
}

Comment: If this is a new site, consider using [Bundles](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) instead of adding scripts individually. There are significant performance benefits and this problem will likely be irrelevant. **Edit:** I've just looked at the graphs at that link and they appear to be deceptive (no metrics, different scale), however, the tables below show hard numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that can really cause this is using a relative URL to reference the file. When just loading the domain without a path, a reference like `Scripts/foo.js` will properly be retrieved at the URL: `http://domain.com/Scripts/foo.js`. However, with a path like `/Home/Index`, the URL then becomes `http://domain.com/Home/Index/Scripts/foo.js`, which is obviously not correct.

However, in your case here, you're not using completely relative paths, as each is prefixed with `/` which *should* cause it to always reference from the site root, despite the current URL path. If we are to assume that you copied and pasted this directly from your project, I'm a bit at a loss how you could be experiencing this issue. First, verify that the code you posted here is in fact what you have in your layout. Then, make sure that the views are using the correct layout, and that you've done silly things like saved the file in case you made changes recently. Short of that, try doing a hard refresh in your browser and/or clear the cache, to make sure it's not simply loading stale pages.

Comment: As always I appreciate the help guys :) I am still unsure what exactly was causing the issue - but after viewing the source and following the links to the javascript files I noticed they were different to those included in my build - changes I had made weren't being updated. So I made an arbitrary change, saved, cleared my browser of all localhost history and voilla! It was the stale page thing after all, I just don't know they were stale.